# Laravel Eloquent 'whereBetween' doesn't work

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, where-clause

I am trying to get a list in a given time period as below:

```
    public function UsersWork()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UsersWork', 'user_id')->whereBetween('end', ["DATE_SUB(CURDATE() INTERVAL 5 YEAR)", date('Y-m-d')]);
    }
```

This is returning the whole list and not just the expected list for time period of 5 years.

Can you pinpoint the reasons for this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `DB::raw()` when you want to use raw sql functions.

```php
public function UsersWork()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UsersWork', 'user_id')
        ->where(function($q){
            $q->where(DB::raw('recur_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()'));
        });
}
```

It may be necessary to add `use DB;` on top before the class declaration.

Comment: The result of your solution says that I have a undefined variable now and with dd() I have no result.

Comment: Try to divide it in two methods. leave `usersWork()` with just `$this->hasMany('App\Models\UsersWork', 'user_id');` and add another function to the same model that extends it with `return $this->usersWork()->where(...`

Comment: It remains the same result